# How to count the occurrence of a value and set that count as a new value for that value's row

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

Title is probably confusing, but let me make it clearer.

Let's say I have a df like this:

```
+----+------+---------------+
| Id | Name | reports_to_id |
+----+------+---------------+
| 0  | A    | 10            |
| 1  | B    | 10            |
| 2  | C    | 11            |
| 3  | D    | 12            |
| 4  | E    | 11            |
| 10 | F    | 20            |
| 11 | G    | 21            |
| 12 | H    | 22            |
+----+------+---------------+
```

I would want my resulting df to look like this:

```
+----+------+---------------+-------+
| Id | Name | reports_to_id | Count |
+----+------+---------------+-------+
| 0  | A    | 10            | 0     |
| 1  | B    | 10            | 0     |
| 2  | C    | 11            | 0     |
| 3  | D    | 12            | 0     |
| 4  | E    | 11            | 0     |
| 10 | F    | 20            | 2     |
| 11 | G    | 21            | 2     |
| 12 | H    | 22            | 1     |
+----+------+---------------+-------+
```

But this what I currently get as a result of my code (that is wrong):

```
+----+------+---------------+-------+
| Id | Name | reports_to_id | Count |
+----+------+---------------+-------+
| 0  | A    | 10            | 2     |
| 1  | B    | 10            | 2     |
| 2  | C    | 11            | 2     |
| 3  | D    | 12            | 1     |
| 4  | E    | 11            | 2     |
| 10 | F    | 20            | 0     |
| 11 | G    | 21            | 0     |
| 12 | H    | 22            | 0     |
+----+------+---------------+-------+
```

with this code:

```
df['COUNT'] = df.groupby(['reports_to_id'])['id'].transform('count')
```

Any suggestions or directions on how to get the result I want? All help is appreciated! and thank you in advance!

Comment: What are you counting?

Comment: oh my apologies for not making it clear. I am wanting to count the the 'reports_to_id' and place that count into where id = reports_to_id. I hope that made more sense. Notice how two people reports to the person with ID 10, and then in the result I want the person with id = 10 to have a count of 2.

Comment: If df1 is the input and df2 is the output why does df2 contain a row ```| 0  | A    | 10            | 2     |``` when df1 contains this entry, so the count value should be 1 not 0?

Comment: oh that's an example of what's happening with the code I have.
df['COUNT'] = df.groupby(['reports_to_id'])['id'].transform('count')

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `value_counts` to count the `reports_to_id` by values, then `map` that to `Id`:

```
df['COUNT'] = df['Id'].map(df['reports_to_id'].value_counts()).fillna(0)
```

Output:

```
   Id Name  reports_to_id  COUNT
0   0    A             10    0.0
1   1    B             10    0.0
2   2    C             11    0.0
3   3    D             12    0.0
4   4    E             11    0.0
5  10    F             20    2.0
6  11    G             21    2.0
7  12    H             22    1.0
```

Similar idea with `reindex`:

```
df['COUNT'] = df['reports_to_id'].value_counts().reindex(df['Id'], fill_value=0).values
```

which gives a better looking `COUNT`:

```
   Id Name  reports_to_id  COUNT
0   0    A             10      0
1   1    B             10      0
2   2    C             11      0
3   3    D             12      0
4   4    E             11      0
5  10    F             20      2
6  11    G             21      2
7  12    H             22      1
```

Comment: Could you explain this code a lil more in depth. df['COUNT'] = df['Id'].map(df['reports_to_id'].value_counts()).fillna(0)
I am having some troubles wrapping my head around it

Comment: `value_counts()` returns a count series indexed by the unique values, e.g. `10:2`. `df['Id'].map(..)` replaces the `id` by the count at the same index (with the `id`). `fillna(0)` replaces all `nan`, corresponding to not-found `id`, with `0`.

Answer (score 0):

You can try the following:

```
l=list[df['reports_to_id']
df['Count']=df['Id'].apply(lambda x: l.count(x))
```